# Could you please verify my cloudbuild.yaml file?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

I am new to setup CI CD pipeline for my nodejs application using GCP cloud build. Below are the steps that I have done:

1. Writing the cloudbuild.yaml file. Done
2. Mirrored the bitbucket repository in my GCP cloud source repository. Done
3. Configured the Webhook triggers in my GCP. Done
4. When I push the code, it gets triggered. Done

Cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: "node:8.13"
  args: ["npm", "install"]
- name: "node:8.13"
  args: ["npm", "test"]
- name: "node:8.13"
  args: ["npm", "run", "build"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', '[job_scheduling]', '--source=.', '--runtime', '[nodejs8.17]', '--trigger-http', '--allow-unauthenticated', '--entry-point=App']
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "groups",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test/GET.js test/POST.js test/PUT.js test/DELETE.js",
    "coverage":"nyc --reporter=text --reporter=lcov mocha test/GET.js test/POST.js test/PUT.js test/DELETE.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.9.1",
    "is-my-json-valid": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^7.0.1",
    "nyc": "^15.0.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

When I push the code in my bitbucket repository, the build gets triggered and I get the below logs:

```
starting build "43d640c7-159e-45d2-9d69-af1c03892f8e"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
 * branch            5fa3b874c8929f410f3249eedeab8 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 5f57724 cloudbuild.yaml edited online with Bitbucket
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: node:8.13
Step #0: 8.13: Pulling from library/node
Step #0: 54f7e8ac135a: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: d6341e30912f: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 087a57faf949: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 5d71636fb824: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 0c1db9598990: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 89669bc2deb2: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 4c84cd37194c: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: a8061553ef43: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 5d71636fb824: Waiting
Step #0: 0c1db9598990: Waiting
Step #0: 89669bc2deb2: Waiting
Step #0: 4c84cd37194c: Waiting
Step #0: a8061553ef43: Waiting
Step #0: 087a57faf949: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 087a57faf949: Download complete
Step #0: d6341e30912f: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: d6341e30912f: Download complete
Step #0: 54f7e8ac135a: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 54f7e8ac135a: Download complete
Step #0: 89669bc2deb2: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 89669bc2deb2: Download complete
Step #0: 5d71636fb824: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 5d71636fb824: Download complete
Step #0: a8061553ef43: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: a8061553ef43: Download complete
Step #0: 4c84cd37194c: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 4c84cd37194c: Download complete
Step #0: 0c1db9598990: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 0c1db9598990: Download complete
Step #0: 54f7e8ac135a: Pull complete
Step #0: d6341e30912f: Pull complete
Step #0: 087a57faf949: Pull complete
Step #0: 5d71636fb824: Pull complete
Step #0: 0c1db9598990: Pull complete
Step #0: 89669bc2deb2: Pull complete
Step #0: 4c84cd37194c: Pull complete
Step #0: a8061553ef43: Pull complete
Step #0: Digest: sha256:3ecf259bf23f8a75555cf0b92ac5ad3c746e7e2262e937a9bed9ca1685f8e1c7
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for node:8.13
Step #0: docker.io/library/node:8.13
Step #0: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
Step #0: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
Step #0: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No description
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No repository field.
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No README data
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No license field.
Step #0: 
Step #0: up to date in 0.447s
Step #0: found 0 vulnerabilities
Step #0: 
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image: node:8.13
Step #1: npm ERR! path /workspace/package.json
Step #1: npm ERR! code ENOENT
Step #1: npm ERR! errno -2
Step #1: npm ERR! syscall open
Step #1: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
Step #1: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
Step #1: npm ERR! enoent 
Step #1: 
Step #1: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #1: npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-04-15T18_49_03_616Z-debug.log
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "node:8.13" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 254
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Update:
When I run your code:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: "ls"
  args: ["-la", "/workspace"]
```

Below are the logs:

```
[![starting build "363526b2-37f7-4b5a-9ee6-599db1442933"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
 * branch            98a8af215a8e683f94558a6351af60512b6fa1d7 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 98a8af2 cloudbuild.yaml edited online with Bitbucket
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:17 .git
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:17 API
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 16 14:17 UI
PUSH
DONE][1]][1]
```

[image]

I have attached the screenshot of my project structure.

Comment: Can you show your project structure? or add this first step `- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" \n entrypoint:"ls" \n args: ["-la","/workspace"]` (inline representation with \n for new line in comment... paste the result in your question update.)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have pasted the result and also the screenshot of my project structure in my question. My **cloudbuild.yaml** and **package.json** files are in my _/API/groups_ directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have configured your trigger to use the `/api/groups/cloudbuild.yaml` file but the root of your git repository is `/`

Update your `cloudbuild.yaml` steps by adding the `dir` param for setting the correct working directory

```
- name: "node:8.13"
  args: ["npm", "install"]
  dir: 'API/groups'
...
```

Full doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config)